# The condition `WHERE Id = 14317961` in my query is invalid

Tags: javascript

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
           'SELECT Id, Criteria, CpcBid, FirstPageCpc, FirstPositionCpc, TopOfPageCpc, Criteria ' +
           'FROM   KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
           'WHERE' + 
           'Id = 14317961 ' + 
           'DURING LAST_7_DAYS ');
var rows = report.rows();

while(rows.hasNext()) {
    var row = rows.next();
    var keywordIdReport = row['Id'];
    var keywordNameReport = row['Criteria'];
    var cpcBid = row['CpcBid'];
    var firstPageCpc = row['FirstPageCpc'];
    var firstPositionCpc = row['FirstPositionCpc'];
    var topOfPageCpc = row['TopOfPageCpc'];

    Logger.log('KeywordIdReport :' + keywordIdReport)
    Logger.log('CPCbid :' + cpcBid)
    Logger.log('firstPositionCpc : ' + firstPositionCpc)
    Logger.log('topOfPageCpc : ' + topOfPageCpc)
    Logger.log('firstPageCpc : ' + firstPageCpc)
}
```

I don't understand why, but the Adwords IDE tell me that the condition `WHERE Id = 14317961` in my query is invalid, but I can't explain it is wrong. Assume here that the current Id exists. The purpose of that query is to access the three fields `firstPositionCpc`, `topOfPageCpc` and `firstPageCpc` for the specific keyword id. How could I fix my problem?

Comment: Try giving a space after your where clause `'WHERE ' +`.

Comment: AbdullahKhan is correct: `WHEREId = 14317961 ` is the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try giving a space after your where clause `'WHERE ' +`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no space after the `'WHERE' +`

Add a space after it `'WHERE ' +`.

Answer (score 1):

missing space after " WHERE "

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
       'SELECT Id, Criteria, CpcBid, FirstPageCpc, FirstPositionCpc, TopOfPageCpc, Criteria ' +
       'FROM   KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
       'WHERE ' +  <----- space was missing 
       'Id = 14317961 ' + 
       'DURING LAST_7_DAYS ');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query, no spaces are available between 'where' and 'ID', please add a space between those.

```
'WHERE ' + 
'Id = 14317961 ' +
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the space after the `WHERE` keyword, it should be as shown below:

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
           'SELECT Id, Criteria, CpcBid, FirstPageCpc, FirstPositionCpc, TopOfPageCpc, Criteria ' +
           'FROM   KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT ' +
           'WHERE ' + 
           'Id = 14317961 ' + 
           'DURING LAST_7_DAYS ');
```